# android push notification is not working when app Killed or force stop in Mi 4i

Tags: android

android push notification is not working when app Killed or force stop in Mi 4i
I wrote code  android firebase push notification is working fine in Moto g4 and Smsung S6 but its not working in Xaimoi Mi 4i when app is killed.

I am sending data in format data payload for example:

```
{
    "to":"firebase_id",
    "data":{
        "message":"push notification finally received",
        "title":"hello firebase"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i doubt that there is an awnser to it, if whole app is killed(not only closed activities, killed services too) - there is no solution to this problem, but it should work just fine after app is launched again